# Rendering third-party responsive content on non-responsive publisher sites

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

I'm developing a third-party application that is intended to be responsive on the sites it will be placed in. This "widget" will be placed on sites that are often non-responsive. I am using CSS media queries to detect screen sizes like so:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  /* STYLES */
}
```

and also detecting mobile browsers to fire various mobile specific JavaScript functions like so:

```
 var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

 if(isMobile) {
   // Do Something
 }
```

These styles and functions work great when I test them on a publisher's site that is responsive, but does not execute (defaults to desktop styles and JS) when the widget is being placed on a non-responsive site. The only way I can get the non-responsive site to play nice is with inserting the following meta tag to restrict zooming on the publisher's page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Ideally, I would not restrict the zooming of the browsers on the non-responsive mobile sites that the widget is published on. Is there anything I can do to avoid adding this tag?

In general, what can I do to ensure my mobile-specific styles and JS run correctly when placed on a non-responsive publisher's site?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: If the whole page your widget gets embedded in is not responsive, then what’s the point of having your widget behave responsive in that case? What’s the actual harm in your “desktop” styles and script getting executed then?

Comment: @CBroe: Our desktop styles are relatively unusable on mobile devices. We have a fixed element that sits on the side of the window. Clicking on this triggers an overlay to appear. This overlay is not usable on a mobile device.